# Difference in behavior with case objects extending traits

Tags: scala

I was looking at a scala project on github to learn scala when i came across the `Case1` snippet. A trait extends the Scala `Product` trait and then a case object extends that trait. This compiles just fine.
To understand this better i tried out `Case2` which does not seem to compile and it asks me to define the `absMethod()` in the case object.
I cannot understand why this does not happen in the first case.

```
//Case 1
sealed abstract trait test1 extends Product with Serializable
case object test11 extends test1
test11.productArity  

//Case 2  
trait abstact extends Any{
  def absMethod():Int
}  
sealed abstract trait test2 extends abstact
case object test22 extends test2
test22.absMethod()
```

Comment: Thanks for the question, I posted an answer that will hopefully clarify your doubt. Aside from that, a couple of notes on your code: you do not have to extends `Any` explicitly (a class that extends "nothing" implicitly extends `Any`) and you don't have to annotate your `trait` as `abstract`.

Comment: That's not correct. When a class or trait or object doesn't explicitly extend anything it automatically extends `AnyRef`. If you have a class extending `AnyVal` and want it to inherit from a trait, that trait needs to extend `Any` explicitly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first case compiles because the compiler has special knowledge of `productArity` for case classes/objects. As part of the compilation process, it will not only create a companion object (for case classes), but also implement several methods, such as `equals`, `hashCode`, `productArity` (and more).

If you look at the output of your first test after the typer phase (`scalac -Xprint:typer`):

```
sealed abstract trait test1 extends AnyRef with Product with Serializable;
  case object test11 extends AnyRef with com.github.yuvalitzchakov.TupleTest.test1 with Product with Serializable {
    def <init>(): com.github.yuvalitzchakov.TupleTest.test11.type = {
      test11.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    override <synthetic> def productPrefix: String = "test11";
    <synthetic> def productArity: Int = 0;
    <synthetic> def productElement(x$1: Int): Any = x$1 match {
      case _ => throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(x$1.toString())
    };
    override <synthetic> def productIterator: Iterator[Any] = scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime.typedProductIterator[Any](test11.this);
    <synthetic> def canEqual(x$1: Any): Boolean = x$1.$isInstanceOf[com.github.yuvalitzchakov.TupleTest.test11.type]();
    override <synthetic> def hashCode(): Int = -877171150;
    override <synthetic> def toString(): String = "test11";
    <synthetic> private def readResolve(): Object = com.github.yuvalitzchakov.TupleTest.test11
}
```

You can see how the compiler implemented `productArity` and assigns `0` (since an object has no constructor arguments), which was abstract on `Product`. In the case of your custom defined abstract method, you have to fill that on your own, hence the compiler complains when it doesn't find an implementation.

Comment: Ahhhh...  This is very very helpful. I was completely at a fix. So which one is the better practice to follow?  I need to learn looking at the outputs at each phase. Any recommendation on where i can learn this ?

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya The first thing I would go through is to learn about case classes, their purpose and how the compiler provides some additional helper methods so we don't have to explicitly lay them out. Later, as you get more comfortable with the language, a quick `scalac -Xshow-phases` can get you started.

Comment: yeah i was aware of the case classes providing default impls for general methods like toString ,getter ,setters etc . I just had no idea that productArity was one off them. Most books do not cover it.

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya Yes, because that's a compiler implementation detail, which may change in the future. As a language author, you never want to put things like that as part of a book .

Comment: got it !  Thanks again :)

Comment: I am not sure I agree it's an implementation detail. I was surprised it isn't actually part of specification, but case classes/objects no longer extending `Product` would be a _very_ large change (and `productArity` being a member of `Product` is specified). I'd rather explain it by `productArity` not being useful all that often :)

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I think I agree with that statement :). I went through the specification while answering this question and could find nothing in regards to `productArity`. I do understand that *dropping* the implementation would be a huge breaking change, but I take everything not in the spec with a grain of salt, so I rather treat it explicitly as an implementation detail.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It's in http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#tuple-types :)

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov That's the definition for a tuple type. Although it does mention that a tuple type *is a* case class with numeric selectors, it doesn't mention anything in the case class section, where it does go to length about the methods provided by the compiler http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/05-classes-and-objects.html#case-classes, which is what I found odd.

Answer (score 1):

That happens because the `case object` is concrete and needs to have an implementation of its abstract parent class. For example, this will work and print `42`:

```
trait Abstract {
  def method(): Int
}  

sealed trait Test2 extends Abstract

case object Test22 extends Test2 {
  def method(): Int = 42
}

Test22.method()
```

For the first case, `case class`es and `case object`s are `Product`s and the fields for them are generated at compile time. For example, a `case class` with two fields is also a `Product` with arity 2, just like a `Tuple2[A, B]` (`(A, B)`, a pair).

Comment: yes i get that but i cannot understand why in the first case i dont see any errors.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the question right. Added a clarification, hope this helps.